# CSS keep div border from showing through a span

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/yh1gykgs/1/

I am trying to have the header "Hello" background be transparent.... but I don't want the white div border to cross-over into the "Hello" header background.  I'm not sure how I can do this.

The second part in the fiddle is the effect I'm trying to achieve.

```css
img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.header{
 padding-top:10px;

}

.section{
position:relative;
}

#second{
 height:635px;
 padding-top
}
.about-us-info {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
    height: 313px;
    border: 2px solid #3c3c3c;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -450px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -160px;
}
span.span-header {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    /* margin-top: -22px; */
    position: relative;
    font-size: 34px;
    background: white;
    width: 420px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -21px;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: latobold;
}
.about-us-info p {
    text-align: center;
    /* line-height: 28px; */
    line-height: 1.65em;
 
}
.about-us-info p.first {

    margin-top:35px;
}
/*--------------------------------------Third Section--*/

#services-info{
 height:250px;
 margin-top:-125px;
 border:2px solid white;
}
#services-header{
background:red;
color:white;

}

/*--------------------------------------Fourth Section--*/
```

```html
 <div class="section" id="third">
  <img src="http://www.wildlifetrusts.org/sites/default/files/images/Planting%20along%20realigned%20River%20Chelt%20Gloucs%20WT,%20EA%20and%20landowner2%20comp.jpg">
     <div class="about-us-info" id="services-info">
            <span class="span-header" id="services-header">Hello</span>
            <p class="first">Blah Blah <br>
            Blah BLah
            </p>
            <p> Blah Blah <br>
             Blah Blah<br>
             Blah Blah <br>
             Blah Blah<br>
             Blah Blah
            </p>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You mean, you dont want to remove the border completely but you dont want to see it under hello header when it is transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have solved the problem : https://jsfiddle.net/Microsmsm/yh1gykgs/4/

[**Refrence**](https://css-tricks.com/line-on-sides-headers/)

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: lato-reg;
  src: url(fonts/lato/Lato-Regular.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: latobold;
  src: url(fonts/lato/Lato-Bold.ttf);
}
body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: lato-reg;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #3c3c3c;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.section {
  position: relative;
}
/*--------------------------------------First Section--*/

#first > img {
  position: relative;
}
.first-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
.first-wrapper img {
  position: relative;
  height: initial;
  width: initial;
}
.first-wrapper h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-size: 54px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-top: 95px;
  font-family: lato-reg;
  letter-spacing: .16em;
}
.first-wrapper p {
  line-height: 29.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}
/*--------------------------------------Second Section--*/

#second {
  height: 635px;
  padding-top
}
.about-us-info {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 900px;
  height: 313px;
  /*     border: 2px solid #3c3c3c; */
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -450px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -160px;
}
span.span-header {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  /* margin-top: -22px; */
  position: relative;
  font-size: 34px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -21px;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: latobold;
}
.about-us-info p {
  text-align: center;
  /* line-height: 28px; */
  line-height: 1.65em;
}
.about-us-info p.first {
  margin-top: 35px;
}
/*--------------------------------------Third Section--*/

/* #services-info{
  height:250px;
  margin-top:-125px;
  border:2px solid white;
} */

#services-header {
  color: white;
}
#services-header:before,
#services-header:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  top: 15px;
  width: 600px;
}
#services-header:before {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
#services-header:after {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
/*--------------------------------------Fourth Section--*/

#sample {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
#sample-header {
  background: #F3F5F6;
}
```

```html
<div class="section" id="third">
  <img src="http://www.wildlifetrusts.org/sites/default/files/images/Planting%20along%20realigned%20River%20Chelt%20Gloucs%20WT,%20EA%20and%20landowner2%20comp.jpg">
  <div class="about-us-info" id="services-info">
    <span class="span-header" id="services-header">Hello</span>
    <p class="first">Blah Blah
      <br>Blah BLah
    </p>
    <p>Blah Blah
      <br>Blah Blah
      <br>Blah Blah
      <br>Blah Blah
      <br>Blah Blah
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<h2>
  What I want it to look like:
  </h2>
<div class="section" id="fourth">

  <div class="about-us-info" id="sample">
    <span class="span-header" id="sample-header">Hello</span>
    <p class="first">Blah Blah
      <br>Blah BLah
    </p>
    <p>Blah Blah
      <br>Blah Blah
      <br>Blah Blah
      <br>Blah Blah
      <br>Blah Blah
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Snorlax please check this answer ^_-

Comment: you should explain what you have done and I think he dont want to hide the line under the header but he just want to make the header transparent as you can see 'what I want' example.

Comment: you are right but he asked the question the wrong way, you have done a great job. A suggestion for you: if you want to get more reputation then you should explain what you have done what you have added or changed so that other people can get the point easily. :-)

Comment: I have added a reference right @Snorlax ? please check as the right answer ?

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I needed, definitely not the solution that I thought it was going to be but it works!

Answer (score 0):

In  #services-info id, change border to 0px, like so:

```
  #services-info{
    height:250px;
    margin-top:-125px;
    border:0px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It didn't work for me, can you share a fiddle?  I updated my fiddle to show what I wanted.

Comment: Strange... I was using your fiddle. Let me check once more.

Comment: The problem is in #service-info. Please check again and let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: That removes the border entirely, I want the white border to stay there but not overlap the header span.

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry but I don't understand want you want to do.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Just take out the span of the div **services-info**

```
<span class="span-header" id="services-header">Hello</span>
```

then apply this css to it

```
span.span-header{
    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 33%;
    width: 450px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, can you share a fiddle?  I updated my fiddle to show what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div class="span-header-border"></div>
<span class="span-header" id="services-header">Hello</span>
<div class="span-header-border"></div>
```

---

```
#services-info{
  height:250px;
  margin-top:-125px;
  border:2px solid white;
  border-top: none;
}
#services-header{
  background:transparent;
  color:white;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}
.span-header-border {
  height: 2px;
  width: 35%;
  background: white;
  float: left;
}
```